# Disabling audio.play() in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, audio, internet-explorer-8

I am attempting to get a webpage to play a short notification sound whenever an icon changes colour. Using HTML5 this is the very simple matter of:

```
audio.play('ping.mp3');
```

...however, I need IE8 compatibility and audio.play() obviously causes an error whenever running in IE8 since the browser does not support HTML5.

I can live without the sound playing for IE8 users as there will still be a visible indication on screen, I just need to IE8-proof the code such that it doesnt throw an error and stop the script.

Comment: Could you do something super simple and just do `if(audio && audio.play) audio.play()`? Or check that `typeof audio.play === 'function'` before actually running it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check first if you can create the element. If yes, then it means audio tags are supported and then you can proceed with your code playing the audio

```
 var hasAudioSupport = !!(document.createElement('audio').canPlayType);
```